# WCF Service not working from Visual Studio due to SSL

Tags: wcf, ssl, visual-studio-2012, web-config

I've recently added HTTPS to my WCF service, which is working correctly on my development IIS server, for both HTTP and HTTPS.  However, now when I try to run using Visual Studio (localhost), I'm getting this error when trying to hit the service:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Description: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint    with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]. 
Timestamp: 5/15/2013 4:23:04 PM
Client IP Address/DNS Name: ::1 - ::1

at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri,    Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
```

Here is my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="sslBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="HistoryService">
      <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IHistoryService" />
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IHistoryService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="sslBinding" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttp">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

It would be very nice if I could continue to develop using Visual Studio's dev server. Is there something I need to enable with the Visual Studio Development Server for it to work with HTTPS?  Or is there something I can modify in my web.config to make it play nicely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built-in web server in visual studio does not support SSL. Here's a nice tutorial on using IIS Express. I use Microsoft WebMatrix which makes setting up sites using IIS Express simple.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Comment: I was thinking that I didn't want to use IIS Express for this, but that link made setting everything up easy.  Thanks!